# I can not retrieve all post / request variable when press add to cart button. I can only retrieve product id variable

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

on Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart

i put this code

Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('qty')

but the result is empty

Comment: Can I know the purpose of doing this?

Comment: In which area you put this code Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('qty') in this file on Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart

Comment: i put it in getAddUrl function

Comment: You want all qty which is in cart am I right?

Comment: I want to see product quantity of the user input.

Answer (score 0):

if I get it right, you want to track the parameters passed to the cart from some page.
Clicking on the "add to cart" button, 2 parameters will be passed, the Product and the Qty. 
You can do it with:

```
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->load(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0));
```

doing so you will have a object product that is the one who you have passed as a param.
So, now you can have all the products infos you need just doing:

```
     $name = $product->getName();
     $price = $product->getPrice();
     $qty =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('qty', 1),
```

EDIT:

if you want to change buttons instructions you should check the template file in question:

> app/design/frontend/TEMPLATE_PKG/TEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

But for best practice you should never modify the magento's files, so i suggest to override the template file and make your own changes.
Here is a simple guide where you can get these infos: https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/override-phtml-or-layout-core-files-in-magento.html

in your specific case you would like to change the "onclick" function on the button, to point it whereever you want. And you can for sure add new custom buttons and so on.
hope to solve your dubts.

Comment: i want to parsing some value when user click add to cart button to back end

Comment: To achieve this functionality you need to create observer

Comment: Yes, this code is for observers purposes but you can place it also on the cart page and get the params from there. I still didn't get where you want to show those infos. @user10753113

Comment: i want to separate add to cart button (not go to paying page) and buy button (go to paying page)

Comment: I'v just edit my answer, check it. I'm still confused on what is your goal, but I think i reach it with the last edit. Let me know